# Запятые в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть запрос MySQL:

```
UPDATE `taskrun` SET `taskrun` = `taskrun`,1 WHERE `login` = '$usernaame'
```

т.е. мне нужно, чтобы в таблицу записавалось то, что там уже есть и + к этому приписывало ,1

Т.е. в таблице есть уже 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 мне нужно, чтобы потом еще к этим строчкам прибавилось ,1

Comment: т.е. нужно к тому, что уже есть в строке приписать новое. в нашем случае это ,1

Comment: в таблице taskrun поле с названием taskrun?

Answer (score 2):

так ?

```
UPDATE taskrun SET taskrun = CONCAT(taskrun,',1') WHERE login = '$usernaame'
```